# How to print a range of sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that adds new worksheets labelled "Costing Sheet (2)", "Costing Sheet (3)", etc. between the sheets `Line Item Summary` (Sheet7) and `Comparison Job` (Sheet17). I do not know how many of these sheets will be added, this is determined by the user.

How can I print sheets that are added in between? Essentially, I would like the `Line Item Summary` plus any "Costing Sheets" to be printed NOT `Comparison Job` (only sheets up to this).

**EDIT: The code below is used to add new sheets

```
Sub NewSheet()

Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Line Item Summary")
Worksheets(Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Index + 1).Activate

'Active Tab
ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not have any code to print sheets at the moment

Comment: Question has been edited to include the code

Comment: Just loop the sheets by index then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a another version using `LIKE` and `Wildcard (*)`. This will check only for the sheets that **needs** to be printed.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Line Item Summary" Or ws.Name Like "Costing Sheet*" Then
            ws.PrintOut
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

> Will keep that in mind! Can this code be altered to perform the opposite, as suggested by the previous code? Users might change the names of these "Costing Sheets (*)" but will still be in between Line Item Summary and Comparison Job – icalderon 31 mins ago

Is this what you are trying? I have taken care of few **Checks**. You may have to edit it to make it more robust.

```
Option Explicit

Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsStartIndex As Long, wsEndIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wsName As String

    '~~> Loop through the sheet and get the positions of the sheets
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        wsName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        If wsName = "Line Item Summary" Then wsStartIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Index
        If wsName = "Comparison Job" Then wsEndIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Index

        If wsStartIndex <> 0 And wsEndIndex <> 0 Then Exit For
    Next i

    '~~> Do necessary checks
    If wsStartIndex = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Line Item Summary Sheet not found"
    ElseIf wsEndIndex = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Comparison Job Sheet not found"
    ElseIf wsEndIndex < wsStartIndex Then
        MsgBox "Comparison Job is before Line Item Summary. Sheets cannot be printed"
    '~~> If everything is ok then print
    ElseIf wsStartIndex <> 0 And wsEndIndex <> 0 Then
        For i = wsStartIndex To (wsEndIndex - 1)
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name <> "Costing Sheet" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).pritnout
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works well! Just wondering if there's a way to exclude the original sheet named  "Costing Sheet" without any variations to the name

Comment: sorry was having my dinner... You can also use `"Costing Sheet (*"`

Comment: sorry was having my dinner... You can also use `"Costing Sheet (*"`

Comment: Will keep that in mind! Can this code be altered to perform the opposite, as suggested by the previous code? Users might change the names of these "Costing Sheets (*)" but will still be in between `Line Item Summary` and `Comparison Job`

Comment: yup so if the position of the sheet `Line Item Summary` is `5` and then position of `Comparison Job` is `8` so you want to print sheets 5,6 and 7?

Comment: That is correct, but it will not necessarily be in order. In my case `Line Item Summary` is `Sheet7` and `Comparison Job` is `Sheet17`. The new sheets that will be added will be random Sheet#.

Comment: till the time `Comparison Job` is after `Line Item Summary`, it is ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206365/discussion-between-icalderon-and-siddharth-rout).

Comment: Sorry to open this up again, but is there a way to include a line of code that ignores "Costing Sheet". This sheet had to be placed between `Line Item Summary` and `Comparison Job` for my other codes to work

Answer (score 1):

Loop all the sheets by name then make a If it doesn't begin by your 2 sheets name

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count


           If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = "Line Item Summary" Or ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = "Comparaison Job" then

          'Don't print

         Else 

           ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).PrintOut

         Next I

         End If

      End Sub
```

Comment: A "Next without For" error comes up when I try this code

Comment: It's missing an `End If`.

Comment: "Line Item Summary" needs to be printed  as well :)

Comment: I added the `End If` but the same error is still coming up

Comment: Add the `End If` before the `Next I`, not after it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have edited the code to include it, thanks!

Comment: Getting closer but now another error pops up "PrintOut method of Worksheet class failed"